# JQuery - Trigger notification on load instead of onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this html and JQuery-fuction, the fuction triggers when I click the button.
And what is happening then is that a notification window shows up, then auto close.
But I don't want the function to trigger when I click the button. I want it to trigger when another function triggers. Can I use some kind of document-ready-function here, or what should I do?

html:

```
<button type="button" data-type="success" class="btn btn-success notification" data-message="<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='padding-right:6px'></i> User is online" data-horiz-pos="right" data-verti-pos="bottom">Success</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(this).data("type") == 'success') {
                        jSuccess(
                            $(this).data("message"), {
                                HorizontalPosition: $(this).data("horiz-pos"),
                                VerticalPosition: $(this).data("verti-pos"),
                                ShowOverlay: $(this).data("overlay") ? $(this).data("overlay") : false,
                                TimeShown: $(this).data("timeshown") ? $(this).data("timeshown") : 2000,
                                OpacityOverlay: $(this).data("opacity") ? $(this).data("opacity") : 0.5,
                                MinWidth: $(this).data("min-width") ? $(this).data("min-width") : 250
                            });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  What I hear is that you have a JavaScript function that executes when a button is clicked.  However what you want is that you don't want the function executed at that time but instead when another function is executed.  Can you not call your first function from your second?

Comment: when I put this fuction inside another fuction, it still only executes when the button is clicked. A I want is a styled alert-modal (like the script I'm trying to use) popping up when my other fuction triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var message;
$(function(){
//Default message
message = function(){
 jSuccess(
    "<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='padding-right:6px'></i> User is online", 
     {
        HorizontalPosition: "right",
        VerticalPosition: "bottom",
        ShowOverlay:  false,
        TimeShown: 2000,
        OpacityOverlay: 0.5,
         MinWidth: 250
  });    
}

message();

$(".btn.btn-success.notification").click(function(){
    message();
});
 
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/217zaqj0/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link, should give you some direction.

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Blake.
Within the

```
//Handler for .ready call
```

you can add your call to jSuccess()

```
jSuccess("Your message", {
    HorizontalPosition: XXX,
    VerticalPosition: XXX,
    ShowOverlay: XXX,
    TimeShown: XXX,
    OpacityOverlay: XXX,
    MinWidth: XXX,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the auto close, set the [autoHide](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jnotify) to false as the default option value is true.

```
jSuccess("Your message", {
                                autoHide: false, //disable auto close
                                HorizontalPosition: 50,
                                VerticalPosition: 50,
                                ShowOverlay: false,
                                TimeShown: 2000,
                                OpacityOverlay:  0.5,
                                MinWidth: 250
                            }
                       );
```